# Ajax форма и загрузка страницы

Tags: ajax

Вот у меня есть код, но он выполняеться при изменении селекта, как мне лучше теперь дописать что бы он же выполнялся при $(window).load()

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/city.php',
            data : { select1: $(this).val() },

             success: function(html) {
$("#result_city").empty();
$("#result_city").append(html);
$("#result_city").css("display", "none");
$("#result_city").fadeIn(800);
                }

        });
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: вынесите функцию, которая внутри change сейчас отдельно, и вызывайте ее в обоих случаях, или когда нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#result_city").empty();
$("#result_city").append(html);
$("#result_city").css("display", "none");
$("#result_city").fadeIn(800);
```

странноватый кусочек, я бы написал так:

```
$('#result_city').hide().html(html).fadeIn(800);
```

А весь код, попробуйте как то так:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 function get_data() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/city.php',
   data: { select1: $(this).val() },
   success: function(html) { $('#result_city').hide().html(html).fadeIn(800); }
  });
 }

 get_data(); // do onload
 $('#select1').change(function(){ get_data(); }); // do onchange
}
</script>
```